# How do I code the ratios of an image in Java to match another image?

Tags: java, geometry

I need help to modify the code so that it represents the quoted bit below. I have drawn a bulls eye, but it is not to the same dimensions. How do I make the dimensions match? My code makes a bulls eye of the wrong size. My code is simply drawing a bulls eye. This is good output, but I would like the picture to have a different aspect ratio. Picture: [image]

So my objective is to make these concentric circles that I drew obey some ratio specifications. The problem is, I have no idea how to do this in Java.
Specificallly:

> ...the radii of the circles proportional to the shortest window dimension, à la the bull's-eye part of the Target Corporation logotype and also so the distance from the closest point to the shortest edge is always the radius of the inner circle.

For reference, here is the Target logo:

[image]

Here is what I have already; my code produces the desired output, but without the correct aspect ratio. I'm still becoming familiar with Java, thank you.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RedTarget extends JPanel
{
  
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    
    int newWidth = (getWidth() / 8);
    int newH = (getHeight() / 8);
    int widthcorner = (getWidth() / 2) - (newH * 3);
    int ywidthcorner = (getHeight() / 2) - (newWidth * 3);
    if (getHeight() < getWidth()) 
    {
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillOval(widthcorner, newH, newH * 6, newH * 6);
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
      g.fillOval(widthcorner + newH, newH * 2, newH * 4, newH * 4); 
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillOval(widthcorner + newH * 2, newH * 3, newH * 2, newH * 2);
    }
    
    else
    {
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillOval(newWidth, ywidthcorner, + newWidth * 6, newWidth * 6);
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
      g.fillOval(newWidth * 2, ywidthcorner + newWidth, newWidth * 4, newWidth * 4);
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
      g.fillOval(newWidth * 3, ywidthcorner + newWidth * 2, newWidth * 2, newWidth * 2);
    }

  

  }
   


  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Red Target");
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 200, 200);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    RedTarget panel = new RedTarget();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Container c = window.getContentPane();
    c.add(panel);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have posted code on here without specifying what is wrong with it.  We expect to see what you expect the code to do, why you expect it to do this, what it is actually doing, and why it is wrong.  Please [edit] your question to include this information, and then I will consider retracting my downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edited. How's that?

Comment: Where do you say what your code is actually doing?

Comment: I tried to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let inner radius is R, medium and large radii are 2R and 3R.
I don't see any clues about margins, so let us assign the narrowest margin = R/4

```
 S = Min(Width, Height)
 L = Max(Width, Height)
   for smaller dimension
 3 * R + 2 * 1/4 * R <= S
   for larger direction
 3 * R + R + 1/4 R <= L
```

So we can choose the largest possible inner radius:

```
 R = Min(2/7 * S, 4/17 * L)
```

Comment: Hm, where in the code would I place this? (Sorry, I'm brand new to Java).

Comment: I think, after `super.paintComponent(g);` Seems that R corresponds to your NewH